We are unable to load the list of templates
I am facing this error whenever I want to create a new unity project we are unable to load the list of available templates at this time. Is there any solution to fix the problem?

I reinstalled unity and unity hub many times but I still have the same error.

unity 2020?? thats old.. i think they turned off some of the old stuff recently

yes, i'm using unity hub 2020. i'll install later version and i hope it works. Thank you.

If it doesn't, check the Unity Hub log, as there might be some error there that will help you troubleshoot.
